# Removing a row based on a condition

Tags: r

```
  my_df <- tibble(
    b1 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
    b2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
    b3 = c(5, 9, 8, NA, 2, 3, 9, 5, NA), 
    b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
    b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
    b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
    b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
    b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
    b9 = c(4, 5, NA, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, NA),
    b10 = c(14, 3, NA, 2, 2, 2, 3, NA, 5))
```

I have a df like this, and would like to tell R to remove all '3' or 'NA' in b10 if b1 = 1. I have tried this with this, but it seems to keep the '3' and 'NA' instead of removing them;

```
new_df <- my_df %>% filter(is.na(b10) | b10 == 3  | b1==1 & b10 ==NA)
```

Comment: To test if a value is NA, always use is.na(). Never use an equality test (==) or other comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
  filter(!(b1 == 1 & (is.na(b10) | b10 == 3)))
```

Edit: assuming you want to remove the rows where the conditions meet

Comment: It seems to work well, however, when I apply this to my large dataset, it come up with an error message; Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.4 Mb

Comment: This means you have memory issue. Consider using `data.table` package then instead of `dplyr` and `tibble`: `my_df <- data.table::data.table(my_df)
my_df <- my_df[!(b1 == 1 & (is.na(b10) | b10 == 3)),]` @lofus77